# Shopware 6 docker | Changes not showing

Tags: docker, ssh, shopware, shopware6

when I try to connect via ssh to my local shopware webserver (`./psh.phar docker:start`) and use `./psh.phar storefront:build` there are no changes in my local project.
Also I recognized that there are no files created inside my project when I create new files via ssh.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: before than use to ./psh.phar storefront:build you must run ./psh.phar docker:ssh  https://github.com/shopware/platform

Comment: @pedram I know that. I recognized that this is happening when I set up a 2nd shop on my local environment. It seems to be a mounting problem. Also I found out that this is just happening with the enabled docker sync option which I need for mac performance

Comment: What is you docker volumes configuration?